# JSXGraph: How do I hide the grid without hiding the axis labels and ticks?

Tags: javascript, jsxgraph

By default, JSXGraph's board renders with a grid in the background. When I instantiate it with the option `axis: false`, the grid disappears, but so do the axis labels and tickmarks.

Messing with JXG.Options like this doesn't seem to do anything:

```
JXG.Options.grid.strokeColor = '#ff0000';
JXG.Options.grid.strokeOpacity = 0;
```

The `grid` board option doesn't actually turn off the grid, just makes it behave differently on zoom, noted [here](https://www.intmath.com/cg3/jsxgraph-axes-ticks-grids.php).

Basically, making the board like this turns off the axis ticks and the grid for the Y axis:

```
var board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard(id, {
  axis: true,
  defaultAxes: {
    y: { ticks: { visible: false } }
  }
});
```

And changing `visible` to `true` makes the grid and the ticks visible.

How do I turn off just the background grid, leaving the axis labels intact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I figured this out by looking at `options.js` in jsxgraph. The main grid is actually referred to as "ticks", closely related to the ticks on the axis line. In fact, it's drawn with the same piece of code I'm guessing. There's `minorHeight` and `majorHeight` for the ticks, referring to either ticks on the axis line or ticks on the entire background. `minorHeight` is 10 by default, and `majorHeight` is -1, a special case that means draw on the whole board. The solution is to change `majorHeight` so it draws like the minor ticks, just a little differently for clarity:

```
var board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard(id, {
  axis: true,
  defaultAxes: {
    y: { ticks: { visible: true, majorHeight: 5 } }
  }
});
```